# proving rules of matrix norms

Tags: matrices

For $$A\in C_{n\times n} \text{ define the norm of A to be } ||A||=max{|[a]_{ij}|}.$$

Prove:
$$
||A+B|| \leq ||A||+||B||
$$

I really don't know how to approach this proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $C=A+B$. Then $c_{ij}=a_{ij}+b_{ij}$, so $|c_{ij}|\le|a_{ij}|+|b_{ij}|$ for each pair $i,j$ with $1\le i,j\le n$. Moreover, each $$|a_{ij}|\le\max_{1\le k,\ell\le n}|a_{k\ell}|=\|A\|\;.$$

Can you finish it from here? Use the fact that if $S$ is a set of numbers, and $x$ is a number such that $s\le x$ for every $s\in S$, then $\max S\le x$ as well.

Comment: can I then say $$|b_{ij}|\leq||B||$$ and then say $$|c_{ij}|\leq||C||$$ and since $$|c_{ij}|\leq|a_{ij}|+|b_{ij}|$$ can I conclude that $$ ||A+B||\leq||A||+||B||$$

Comment: @sarah: I’d say it a bit differently, but I think that you probably have the idea: each $|c_{ij}|\le|a_{ij}|+|b_{ij}|\le\|A\|+\|B\|$, so the maximum of all the $|c_{ij}|$ must be $\le\|A\|+\|B\|$. But the maximum of all the $|c_{ij}|$ **is** $\|A+B\|$, so $\|A+B\|\le\|A\|+\|B\|$.